# Synonym for "without signature"

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for a one word synonym for the notion "Without signature" for the domain of computer science, where "unsigned" usually means "a numerical data type which proscribes negative values", so I do not want to confuse my users.

For my specific scope, the "Without signature" means that a component failed to provide a signed identification (the signature itself) which was signed by a central authority (signing: The component provides an identification text, some operations are performed on it by the central authority in order to generate a unique and valid ID which is the signature)...

A very specific use case (as per David's comments), and I am sorry for the deep technical details:

```
if(component.signature() == unsigned)
{
    // do something with unsigned components
}
else
if(component.signature() == company)
{
    // do something with company signed components
}
else
if(component.signature() == consultants)
{
   // do something with components singed by consultants
}
```

but `unsigned` is a reserved word in most programming languages :(

Comment: IMHO this would not confuse users, because unsigned and signed values are never used in the context of "signature", I have never heard of a use case where the word "signature" was used in relation to signed/unsigned values, while they share the same base word, in the world of computer science, signature and signed/unsigned mean two wholly different things.

Comment: Why does the word you seek have to not be a reserved word? Will you be using this in a programming language? Do you not mark reserved words differently in non-programming text?

Comment: Yes, the word I seek should not be a reserved word in the programming language since it will be used in the source script (just as shown above), and that will not compile if I use the reserved word with other purpose than it was intended to be used. The word will be a sort of additional identifier, thus why I want one word, not two. I know, I could use: `not_signed` or `without_signature` but I like to keep things short, that's why I'd like one word.  :)

Comment: In your case, you could simply use *none*.  However I would suggest adding some leading characters to your enumerations constants to avoid namespace collisions.

Comment: @Jim This is a great idea :) But I really like the "signatureless" from below, so I accept that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conventional term for this is ***unsignatured***.

*[unsignatured](http://universalium.academic.ru/224911/unsignatured)* — adj. * * * unˈsignatured, ppl. a. (un 1 8.) Brydges Censura Lit. III. 342 Such notes..as appear **unsignatured** at the bottom of the page.

*[signature](http://www.websters-online-dictionary.org/definitions/Signaturing)* 2. Base verb from the following inflections: signaturing, **signatured**, signatures, signaturer, signaturers, signaturingly and signaturedly

Also consider:
[sig·na·ture·less](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/signatureless), adjective

Usage examples from different contexts:

> d) Unsignatured ELT Signals The existing 121.5/243 MHz signals are unsignatured, i.e., they do not at present carry any form of unique identifying code to enable the LUT to separate the frequency ... ([Intl. Elec. Elecs. Conf. Proc.](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=7y9GAQAAIAAJ&q=%22unsignatured%22&dq=%22unsignatured%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7s9iUfqtBcLYrQf6woD4BQ&redir_esc=y))
>
> Signatured parts tend to occupy a pitch-range roughly a fifth lower (for one flat) than unsignatured upper parts in the same pieces, … ([Music](http://books.google.com/books?id=JLKlGUajfDoC&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=%22unsignatured%22&source=bl&ots=xmwvsA2Q3D&sig=dm61Jk4yW0qQx0Cl6j-CpCRLNi8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Bs5iUfCDGoqErQeCzIDQDw&sqi=2&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBA))

Answer (score 4):

When *unsigned* is already taken, you just use *not signed*. Or, well, *without signature*. You used these words to explain what you meant to us, so why not use the exact same words to explain it to others.

Comment: Even *not signed* could be considered to be talking about the lack of + or - sign.